# Trying to select the highest date between date ranges in a subquery

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a table using data gotten from 3 tables.

table3 contains rates for different days. The rates aren't measured daily so I simply want to use the most recent date with respect to the table2 record which is what prompts the trigger.

So far this is what I have but I can't seem to get it to work.

I'm not sure I'm explaining myself properly to be honest.

```
CREATE  TRIGGER `trigger1`
AFTER UPDATE ON `table2` FOR EACH ROW


UPDATE `table4`

inner join (SELECT o.`Name`, 
       o.Date,
       (o.`value` * (m.`rate`)) total
  FROM `table1` o
  LEFT JOIN `table2` r
            ON o.`Name` = r.`Name`
           AND o.Date = r.Date
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * from `table3` 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT `Name`, Date
    WHERE Date < r.Date
    ORDER BY Date DESC
    LIMIT 1) as y 
    ON table3.Date = y.Date AND table3.Name = y.Name) m
    ON o.`Name` = m.`Name`
           
GROUP BY o.`Name`, o.Date)x

set `Contribution` = x.total

where (`table4`.Date) = x.Date and `table4`.`Well Name` = x.`Well Name`;
```

fiddle link : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pVqmhmM21XJARKhvFMP52B/4

Comment: Create a model on the online fiddle. Table structures, minimal sample data, update query, desired final data state, explanations.

Comment: The `as y` subquery cannot reference `r` on the inside. You need some kind of lateral join or a sub query.

Comment: @Akina Like this?  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pVqmhmM21XJARKhvFMP52B/2

Comment: Well. Sample data is correct (I have copied it to https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6da147494318a8ae8f04e0fe60d16324, it seems to be more useful for me). Now provide `UPDATE table2 ...` query which must fire the trigger and show final `table4` data state which you want to see after the trigger execution. With detailed explanations.

Comment: How do I show the final table state I want?

Comment: Add query and final data state into question text as an update. format data state as a table.

Comment: @Akina https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pVqmhmM21XJARKhvFMP52B/4